# Jupyter Notebook does not support smileys in MARKDOWN cells

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I'm Windows 10 (64-bit) user and I'm using **Anaconda2** (Python 2.7).

I have created many gists (as Markdown `.md` file) on Github which supports almost all the smileys available in this [Web page](https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/).

When I tried to use `:smile:`, `:boom:` etc. in **Markdown cell** of **Jupyter Notebook**, it did not work and it seems **Jupyter Notebook** does not support smileys.

Please suggest me if there's any way to fix this.

Thanks.

Comment: Jupyter markdown doesn't support Github style markdown, that's why you're not getting emojis

Comment: If you really want to use emoji in your notebook, goto http://getemoji.com/ and copy paste emoji in your markdown cell.

Comment: **@RajmaniArya** suggested correct. https://emojikeyboard.org is also best for quick copy (just 1 click & copy) of emojis.Finally you can use that emoji in **Markdown cells** of **Jupyter Notebook**.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also checked by visiting a lot many sites and found **Jupyter Notebook** does not support Github styled emojis.

**@RajmaniArya** suggested good way in the comment above.

And it brought me to use copy paste technique to use emojis in **Markdown cells** of **Jupyter Notebook**.

https://emojikeyboard.org and https://www.webpagefx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/ are also best to quick copy of emojis as we don't need to do copy paste things (Just one click is enough to copy).

Have a look on the below gif which clears it.

[image]

You can also visit http://getemoji.com/ suggested by **@RajmaiArya** and https://gist.github.com/rxaviers/7360908 to copy and paste emojis if you want other different kind of emojis.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Markdown in Jupyter notebooks doesn't support github-style :emoji: